# Elasticsearch : aggregation "existing" fields

Tags: elasticsearch, aggregation

I'm quite new to ElasticSearch aggregations. I want to be able to count how many documents are retrieved with a not null field.

Here's what I do to count how many documents don't have a `name` field.

```
{
  "size": 3,
  "query": {
    "query_string": {
      "query": "martin"
    }
  },
  "aggs": {
    "results_without_mb_id": {
      "missing": {
        "field": "name"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

It works but I want to do the exact opposite. Is there an `existing` aggregation?

Answer (score 16):

Do this by passing an 'exists' filter to a [filter aggregation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-bucket-filter-aggregation.html). Like above, just replace 'missing' with 'exists', and also add 'filter' key, so:

```
{ "size": 3, 
  "query": {
    "query_string": {
      "query" : "martin"
    } 
  }, 
  "aggs": {
    "results_without_mb_id": { 
       "filter": { 
          "exists": { 
            "field": "name" 
          }  
       } 
    } 
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You want to use the "exists" filter.

http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-exists-filter.html

Here is a sample that finds all the documents where authResult.codeID exists, and then runs an aggregation on it.:

```
GET prodstarbucks/authEvent/_search
{
  "size": 0,
  "query": {
    "filtered": {
      "query": {
        "match_all": {}
      },
      "filter": {
        "exists": {
          "field": "authResult.codeID"
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "aggs": {
    "users": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "authInput.userName.userNameNotAnalyzed",
        "size": 5
      }
    }
  }
}
```

}

Note: If you only want to count the documents you don't even need an aggregation, just use the "total" number of hits returned.

Comment: actually I don't want to change my query. I just want to count the number of documents with a not null "name" (and "age", and ... ).

Comment: "exists" (aka not null) is only valid as a filter option, you can't put it in your query node.  You can combine filters and queries together as I did in my example above.  So you would have "Name" in the exists filter, and your query_string stuff in the query portion.